Animated series Named Bob Mauren?
I remember watching an animated cartoon series named something like "Bob Mauren"
which featured a muscled protagonist named Bob mostly wearing a red t-shirt, and his fellow comrades, a red headed slim girl and taller fat man, and his main enemy (the shows main antagonist) was short fat bald man; I tried looking for this so much but I couldn't find anything, I presume it was in English but I'm not sure, since I saw it dubbed on national TV, can anyone help?

I think it could be Bob Morane.


this is it , exactly , but i remember it had more detailed graphics , anyway thanx , i don't know how i missed this , but i searched a thousand times with different queries , thanx again

Yeah I'm not sure that the picture is in the style of the animated series. But you can google another picture :-P

thanx again , would you mind loooking at my other question too? since you knew this one , you might know that one too

Oh my, loved that, the French knew how to do entertaining and gripping action cartoons (reminds me of Chris Colorado, another amazing series). But yeah, that picture by far doesn't do the actual animation any justice.

Why that blue guy looks like kim possible villain .
